# InterfaceError: Error binding Parameter 5...Django JWT token (django request token tool)

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, jwt

I am trying to set up a "one time use" link creating system with this tool:

https://github.com/yunojuno/django-request-token

I have followed the instructions on the installation and implementation. Now the implementation says that I should create a Requesttoken in the admin interface or with some other method. 
When I go to the admin interface and when I go to add the token, I fill out the scope field which is the only one required and click save. This is where I get the 
InterfaceError:r: Error binding Parameter 5 - probably unsupported type
And the error seems to happen at this line of code:

```
super(RequestToken, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I will include the models.py file:

https://github.com/yunojuno/django-request-token/blob/master/request_token/models.py

This is the file which contains the line of code which is causing the error. 
I am really stuck on this and I hope someone will know how to fix it.

If you dont know how to fix the problem maybe you know some tool which does a simillar thing as this one.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue I had so I wanted to provide the answer on how I did it so if anyone encounters this InterfaceErrror, maybe you can try this. 
Basically Django's default database is SQLite3 but this app requires PostgreSQL which I somehow overlooked, so if you are encountering the "Error binding Parameter 5", maybe you can try changing your database and hopefully that will fix the error as it did for me.

Comment: Yes!  Was running tests against SQLLite and had a (pgSQL) JSONField.